# What does this mean: $foo = new $foo();?

Tags: php

I've never seen something like this before.

```
$dbTable = new $dbTable();
```

**We are storing an Object Instance inside $dbTable ?**

**Are we transforming a string into an object ?**

Here's the context:

```
protected $_dbTable;

    public function setDbTable($dbTable)
    {
        if (is_string($dbTable)) {
            $dbTable = new $dbTable();
        }
        if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
        }
        $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
        return $this;
    }
```

From php manual here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

We can read:

> If a string containing the name of a
>   class is used with new, a new instance
>   of that class will be created. If the
>   class is in a namespace, its fully
>   qualified name must be used when doing
>   this.

But this seems to be a concatenation operation between a string and those "things": () - without using a dot. So I'm still not sure about what's going on here.

Comment: class_exists() would be better than is_stirng()...

Comment: @smentek: Except that's completely different function.

Comment: @smentek: Not in this case I believe. Because we can well pass a string only. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the line:

```
if (is_string($dbTable)) {
```

Means that a new `$dbTable` will only be instantiated if the input is a string. So what is going on here is that `$dbTable` contains the name of a class that is created when that code executes:

```
$dbTable = new $dbTable();
```

And then later on the code checks to make sure an object of the proper type (`Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`) is created. As Stefan points out, an instance of the class can be passed directly, in which case the code you mentioned is not even executed.

Comment: So, we can say that when we have `$dbTable()`; and $dbTable is a class representation string, we are "concatenating" the `()` with that string, so that `$dbTable();` stays equal to `myClass();` ? If so I'm not understanding why don't we use the dot. :s

Comment: It's not concatenation, it's "variable variables" – http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure of it. After reading your source, I noticed that we can well have this: `${a.$i} = "value";` and here, we have a dot and it will work. Of course we can as well, forget about the dot. BUT, for some reason php accepts the dot? :))

Answer (score 3):

I believe, that what this does – it creates new object from class with name stored in `$dbTable`

```
<?php

class MyClass {
    private $foo = 4;

    public function bar(){
        echo $this->foo;
    }
}

class MyClass2 {
    private $foo = 6;

    public function bar(){
        echo $this->foo;
    }
}

$a = 'MyClass';
$b = new $a();
$b->bar(); //echo '4'

$a = 'MyClass2';
$b = new $a();
$b->bar(); //echo '6'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please keep your answer, because I found it useful to understand the concepts behind this. :)

Answer (score 1):

The method either takes an instance of `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` (or a subclass) as an argument or it takes a string argument with the name of the class to instantiate.

So essentially this allows you to call the method like this:

```
$dbTable = new My_Zend_Db_Table_Class();
$xy->setDbTable($dbTable);

// or

$dbTable = 'My_Zend_Db_Table_Class';
$xy->setDbTable($dbTable);
```

The latter only works if your custom class does not take any constructor argument.

The `$obj = new $className()` syntax allows you to instantiate objects from classes that are determined at runtime.

Comment: Nice! I get it. So that could be the reason why the author first have added the is_string condition and also, created another condition to see if that object is an instance of something. If we have a string, it will grab the string, and convert it into an object and then check if it's of the right type. If we have an object it will only do the later. Is that it ?

Comment: @MEM: Absolutely correct. That's the intention of the given code.